# "pip install -e" cannot find alabaster==0.7.12 only on MacOS

Tags: python, pip

python3.7 and pip18. macos 10.13 setup.py is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='proxy-tools',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'alabaster==0.7.12',
    ],
)
```

and in egg

```
cat requires.txt 
alabaster==0.7.12
```

When I run `pip install -e .`

```
Collecting alabaster==0.7.12 (from proxy-tools==1.0.0)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement alabaster==0.7.12 (from proxy-tools==1.0.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for alabaster==0.7.12 (from proxy-tools==1.0.0)
```

which is odd, because running `pip search alabaster`, I could see it lists a version of 0.7.12

Comment: I have also tried `install_requires=['alabaser',]`, which does not have a version. The same error.

Comment: I reported this as a bug on pip@github

Comment: I have tried it in centos7, ok. But on macos no

Comment: pip install alabaster==0.7.12 working fine in ubuntu18.04, pip 19.0.3 python3.7, maybe you can try clean your pip cache.

Comment: What happens if you directly pass pip the filename of the wheel (that is to say, the `.whl` file linked from https://pypi.org/project/alabaster/#files)?

Comment: Can you add a few `-vvv` to the `pip install` command? maybe the log will provide some additional useful information